# Using Nifi to append rows to a csv

Tags: csv, merge, hive, apache-nifi

We have csv files that are coming in daily from an FTP site. What we need to do is have the new rows from the current day's csv added to the file that currently exists in the HDFS directory. The process we currently have is:

1. Get SFTP processor picks up the files from the site
2. Update Attribute creates an HDFS folder based on the filename
3. Update Attribute also creates a subfolder based on the year
4. The file is then dumped into the HDFS subfolder

There are about 8 separate directories total, i.e., "sales_report", "inventory", "personnel", etc. For each of these folders, we want the csv file within to be appended-to instead of having a new, separate file for every day.

What would be the best way to do this? I know I'll need a csv reader and writer service but I'm not sure which processors to use and what kind of nifi expressions I'll need (if any). Any detailed responses would be appreciated.

Also, technically the resulting file doesn't need to be csv as long as it's in a format that Hive can recognize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PutHDFS processor has a property for Conflict Resolution with an option of Append.

"Appends to the existing file if any, creates a new file otherwise."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Bryan. I was under the impression that this option merely appends characters to the filename (in order to avoid filename conflicts). Is this not the case?

Comment: It appends the content of the flow file to the content that is already there, but it has no knowledge of the data being appended, it just writes more bytes after existing bytes, so it only makes sense for this things that are "appendable" which csv should be